# Workflow Loop and Update

Tags: office-365, designer-workflow

I need to create a workflow using Sharepoint Designer no code allowed, that will launch on list item update (lets call it List A), this workflow must get items from another list (List B) based on some conditions, then, loop through those items, compare them to Original listItem (A) field and according to some condition make an update to the List B item.

hope this is clear. 
my question is is this possible if so can you lead me to good tutorial.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a list workflow using Create item and then set . Its straight forward

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using "Call HTTP Web Service" action in SPD workflow. You can follow below steps.

- Add an action "Call HTTP Web Service" to the workflow step and set request url, headers.
- loop through your results and update your item in List B using "Update List Item" action.

Below is an article explain steps to use the workflow action.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2012/09/04/how-to-work-with-web-service-using-call-http-web-service-action-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/